# Limit screen size in Accessibility Settings for RN apps

Tags: react-native, accessibility, screen

Like how there is maxFontSizeMultiplier to limit how large text sizes can increase, is there a way to do the same for screen sizes - ie limit how large a device can 'zoom-in' to a React Native app using the Accessibility Settings?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about what you're trying to achieve by restricting the user agent's ability to zoom in on the page? Are you concerned with reflow (i.e., changing the presentation of the page content when a user zooms in) or are you just trying to restrict their ability to make the page elements larger? FYI, WCAG 2 requires that users can resize text up to 200% without using assistive technology. It also requires that zoomed in content is reformatted to fit in a single column without losing information.

Comment: All I am hoping for is to limit the scaling of buttons, icons, images etc so that it does not ruin the UX of my app. 

FYI yes, I am aware of the requirements for text and have no issue with scaling text up to 200%. My concern is with everything else in the app.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?